# How do I pull in page's "url path" field, via php, into the theme?

Tags: impresspages

I'm trying to apply the page's url as a `<div>` id to be able to target some css on each individual page. After some characters cleanup I'm hoping to get `<div id="test-page">`.

I have tried pulling it in from the object that I get via

`ipContent()->getBreadcrumb()`

Unfortunately they are all (including one I need) protected and cannot be echoed out.

`[urlPath:protected] => test-page/`

Is there a function that I've missed and can use to pull that in? Or a proper method of getting it from the object? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And of course, as soon as I posted a question I've found the answer:

I could **not** get the protected value from `[urlPath:protected] => test-page/` when doing this:

`$a = ipContent()->getBreadcrumb();
 $a = $a[0];
 $a = $a->urlPath;`

**Solution:** The way you can pull this is is by replacing `$a->urlPath` with `$a->getUrlPath()`.

It will work for all the elements in object. Like: `$a->updatedAt;` needs to be `$a->getUpdatedAt();`